# Group/merge rows when defined columns match and sum up values

Tags: pandas, group-by

How Do I group/merge rows, where multiple defined columns have the same value and display the sums in other columns not relevant for grouping/merging?

In the below example: If rows have the same values in columns "OrgA" to "OrgF" (text – this refers to an org. structure with departments and sub-departments), group/merge rows and add up the numbers in columns "numA" and "numB".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'orgA': ['A','C','A','C','A','C','A','A','A','L'],
        'orgB': ['B',np.nan,'E',np.nan,'B',np.nan,'E','E','E','C'],
        'orgC': ['C',np.nan,'D',np.nan,'C',np.nan,'H','D','H','B'],
        'orgD': ['D',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'D',np.nan,'F',np.nan,'F','S'],
        'orgE': ['E',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'E',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'F'],
        'orgF': ['F',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'F',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
        'numA': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        'numB': [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
  
print(df)  

  orgA orgB orgC orgD orgE orgF  numA  numB
0    A    B    C    D    E    F     1     2
1    C  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     1     2
2    A    E    D  NaN  NaN  NaN     1     2
3    C  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     1     2
4    A    B    C    D    E    F     1     2
5    C  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     1     2
6    A    E    H    F  NaN  NaN     1     2
7    A    E    D  NaN  NaN  NaN     1     2
8    A    E    H    F  NaN  NaN     1     2
9    L    C    B    S    F  NaN     1     2
```

The output is supposed to look as follows:

```
  orgA orgB orgC orgD orgE orgF  numA  numB
0    A    B    C    D    E    F     2     4
1    C  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     3     6
2    A    E    D  NaN  NaN  NaN     2     4
3    A    E    H    F  NaN  NaN     3     6
4    L    C    B    S    F  NaN     1     2
```

Many thanks for your ideas in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of column names to [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), and set `dropna` to `False` so that rows containing nans are not dropped. You can also specify `sort=False` if it is not important to sort the group keys. Applying this to your example, as in

```py
df.groupby(
    ['orgA', 'orgB', 'orgC', 'orgD', 'orgE', 'orgF'],
    dropna=False,
    sort=False
).sum()
```

we get

```
                               numA  numB
orgA orgB orgC orgD orgE orgF            
A    B    C    D    E    F        2     4
C    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      3     6
A    E    D    NaN  NaN  NaN      2     4
          H    F    NaN  NaN      2     4
L    C    B    S    F    NaN      1     2
```